# ASP.NET clear HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, httpcontext

How can I clear the HttpContext.Current.Request.Files list?

After the postback, this still contains the files.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
            this.SaveImages();
}

private Boolean SaveImages()
    {
        //loop through the files uploaded
        HttpFileCollection _files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        //Message to the user
        StringBuilder _message = new StringBuilder("Files Uploaded:<br>");
        try
        {
            for (Int32 _iFile = 0; _iFile < _files.Count; _iFile++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_files[_iFile].FileName))
                {
                    // Check to make sure the uploaded file is a jpg or gif
                    HttpPostedFile _postedFile = _files[_iFile];
                    string _fileName = Path.GetFileName(_postedFile.FileName);
                    string _fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(_fileName);

                    //Save File to the proper directory
                    _postedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("files/") + _fileName);
                    _message.Append(_fileName + "<BR>");
                }
            }
            lblFiles.Text = _message.ToString();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            lblFiles.Text = Ex.Message;
            //Refill images in control????
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            //Clear HttpContext.Current.Request.Files!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show some code and at which event you are doing this??

Comment: Is there any particular reason, that you are trying to save the image on `page_load` event? this looks odd to me!

Comment: I'm just following a tutorial. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you would need to remove the files early? They will be removed when the request has been processed anyway...